# Finding $\frac{2a^5 - 5a^4 + 2a^3 - 8a^2}{a^2 + 1}$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose $a$ is a root of $x^2 + 3x - 1.$ Find $\frac{2a^5 - 5a^4 + 2a^3 - 8a^2}{a^2 + 1}.$

---

I was thinking of factoring the fraction a bit first, than letting $a^2 = 1 - 3a.$ However, that leads nowhere.

Comment: Well I'd substratc $2a^5 + 6a^4 - 2a^3 = 0$ from the top and then keep subtracting multiples of  $a^2 +3a -1 = 0$ and we what sort of thing I get in the end.

Comment: $(2x^3-11x^2+37x-130)(x^2+3x-1)+427x-130$ is the factorization. What next? @fleablood

Comment: I suggest something else.

Comment: Take $a^4$ out of $2a^5 - 5a^4$.

Comment: You have a linear factor there. Find that.

Comment: Then take $a^2$ out of $2a^3 - 8a^2$

Comment: Find that and then take $a^2$ out of the $a^4$ and $a^2$ .

Comment: Thus, the numerator simplifies to $a^2(a^2(2a - 5)+(2a-8))$

Comment: If you want, you may take $2$ out of the second linear factor .

Comment: The denominator need not be simplified. It is simple to get.

Comment: I have an obvious problem now : the answer should not depend upon which root of $x^2+3x-1$ I started with , but $\frac{427a-130}{2-3a}$, which is derived below (and is correct) depends upon which root we chose. In particular the problem is ill-defined, what you need to find has in fact two values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A complete solution. Let $a$ be a root of $x^2+3x-1$. Then

$a^2=1-3a$

$a^3=a-3a^2=a-3(1-3a)=10a-3$

$a^4=10a^2-3a=10(1-3a)-3a=10-33a$

$a^5=10a-33a^2=10a-33(1-3a)=-33+109a$

Therefore the numerator:$$2a^5 - 5a^4 + 2a^3 - 8a^2=
-66+218a-5(10-33a)+2(10a-3)-8(1-3a)=-130+427a$$

and the denominator: $a^2+1=2-3a$.

Let $a'$ be another root of $x^2+3x-1=0$. Then $aa'=-1. a+a'=-3$. Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $2-3a'$. The denominator becomes $$(2-3a)(2-3a')=4+9-6(-3)=13-18=-5.$$ The numerator becomes $$(427a-130)(2-3a')=
854a-260+1281+390a'=1021-1170+464a=464a-149.$$
So the fraction is equal to $$\frac{464a-149}{-5}$$ where $$a=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}.$$

Comment: I guess I was a fool....

Comment: Fool for taking the  longest route

Comment: I hoped to get an integer that way without using the actual value of $a$. But now I do not see how can one avoid substituting $a=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$. The answer is probably irrational.

Comment: There's an error in step 2, where you forgot to multiply $1-3a$ by $3$.

Comment: Right. I will fix it. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: FYI Mathematica tells me that the final result of the reduction should be $427a-130$, which agrees with @SoumyadwipChanda in their comment to the question body.

Comment: I fixed the calculation. But the fraction still is not completely simplified.

Comment: I think the OP may have copied the fraction incorrectly. I have solved several such problems in the past. The result always did not depend on $a$.

Comment: I have completed the solution. It is not pretty, though.

Answer (score 3):

Another way.

For $a^2+3a-1=0$ and $a=\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ we obtain:
$$(a^2-1)^2=9a^2$$ or
$$(a^2+1)^2=13a^2$$ or
$$a^2+1=\sqrt{13}a,$$ which gives: $$\frac{2a^5-5a^4+2a^3-8a^2}{a^2+1}=$$
$$=\tfrac{2a^5+6a^4-2a^3-11a^4-33a^3+11a^2+37a^3+111a^2-37a-130a^2+37a}{\sqrt{13}a}=$$
$$=\tfrac{37-130a}{\sqrt{13}}=\tfrac{37-65(-3+\sqrt{13})}{\sqrt{13}}=\tfrac{232-65\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{13}}.$$
For $a=\frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{2}$ we obtain: $$a^2+1=-\sqrt{13}a,$$ which gives
$$\frac{2a^5-5a^4+2a^3-8a^2}{a^2+1}=\tfrac{-232-65\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{13}}.$$